# How do I split and sort strings in a list using for loops in Python

Tags: python, list, split

Trying to read a file then store it in a list but not getting the desired output:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    #line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
        if words not in lst:
            lst.append(words)
            
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

My Output:

[['Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon'], ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks'], ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun'], ['Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']]

Desired Output:

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Comment: Can you show us the file please?

Comment: Try looping over `words` as well, and add each item to `lst`.

Comment: it seems to be oddly sorted, what is the sorting method ?

Comment: @AnatoleSot Try opening an ASCII table..

Comment: @AnatoleSot that is how the default sort is. It converts the letter to ASCII codes and the ones with the lowest codes are first. Uppercase letters come before lowercase letters on the ascii table

Comment: instead of the `if` I think you could do list intersection like `list.append([value for value in words if value in lst])` or `list.append(list(set(words) & set(lst)))` or similar.

Comment: @JNevill this looks like a homework assignment, so I did not use list comprehensions as it looks like the OP may not understand it.

Comment: @chess_lover_6 That's a good point. Sometimes these pop up and they are obviously homework, but I think you are right. OP, if this is homework, then don't do what I'm saying as it's likely not covered yet.

Comment: @JNevill also I am very bad at list comprehensions, and 90% of the time I use them, they are copied from stackoverflow :).

Comment: @chess_lover_6I hear you. They are oddball shorthand. It's nice to be able to compress a `for thing in list1: if <condition>: list2.append(thing)` into something so compact, but I always have to think through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is loop through all of the words in the sentence, then check if they are already in the list, then append them.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    #line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
       if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
            
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```